# Uploaded HttpPostedFileBase Image not displaying after refresh with FileContentResult Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having an issue with the controller action where I upload an image and the initial POSTed result is displayed in the view without issue. The image is shown normally.

If I refresh or change pages and return, the image will no longer display.

I have checked what the controller action is returning, and it does indeed return the content to the view.

This is the IMG tag that I'm using to call the controller action.

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Display", "Home")" />
```

This is the controller action:

```
    public ActionResult Display()
    {

        var tempModel = new PartialModel();
        tempModel = (PartialModel)Session["Model"];
        var ImageUpload = tempModel.ProductImage;
        if (ImageUpload != null)
        {
            byte[] content = new byte[ImageUpload.ContentLength];
            ImageUpload.InputStream.Read(content, 0, ImageUpload.ContentLength);
            return File(content, ImageUpload.ContentType);
        }

        return null;


    }
```

This is the create action that receives the POST values:

```
    public ActionResult Create(PartialModelStore p)
    {

        Session.RemoveAll();
        //m.initializeModelLists(p);
        Session["Model"] = p;

        //return View("Index", p);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");


    }
```

I'm using the Session to store values because this is just a mock up application.

I have looked into using Data URI but I need to support older browsers, thus I'm using this method.

Comment: Don't you ovewrite  your `Session` object on the other `Actions` in your `Controller`?

Comment: If you mean write over the session object on the other actions then no. The session data is unchanged and I debugged the return values, and the controller action is passing the correct values back to the view.

Comment: What if you only save the image on the Session instead of all the model? And why not saving the image in a folder then return a path?

Comment: It would ideally save it to the session to than move it to a data store. I'll try saving just the image, but I feel the heart of the matter is why the browser is not displaying the data the controller sends back, since as I state previously, the controller does send the correct data to the view.

Comment: Ok.Did you tried with different browsers?

Comment: Yes. The on IE, it retains the correct size of the image but does not display content.